# Error Installing MySqldb 1.2.3 with Python 2.6 Mac osx 10.6

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed XAMPP of PHP and Mysql 5.1, I had installed python 2.6 and now trying to install the MySqldb-1.2.3, But it is giving me following error.

```
sudo python setup.py build running build running build_py copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/MySQLdb running build_ext building '_mysql' extension creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6 gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing
-fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/mysql
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6
-c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o
-mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -arch i386 -arch ppc -D_P1003_1B_VISIBLE -DSIGNAL_WITH_VIO_CLOSE -DSIGNALS_DONT_BREAK_READ -DIGNORE_SIGHUP_SIGQUIT -DDONT_DECLARE_CXA_PURE_VIRTUAL In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:19,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/limits.h:10:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory In file included from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:33:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:35:5: error: #error "Python.h requires that stdio.h define NULL." /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:38:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:40:19: error: errno.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:42:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:44:20: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:56:20: error: assert.h: No such file or directory In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:7:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:58,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:89: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Py_uintptr_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:90: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Py_intptr_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:113: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Py_ssize_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:235:76: error: math.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:242:22: error: sys/time.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:243:18: error: time.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:261:24: error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyport.h:300:22: error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:78,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pymem.h:52: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pymem.h:53: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’ In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:80,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:107: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Py_ssize_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:111: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘Py_ssize_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:137: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:137: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘Py_ssize_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:137: error: ‘Py_ssize_t’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:137: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:157: error: ‘readbufferproc’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:158: error: ‘writebufferproc’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:159: error: ‘segcountproc’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:160: error: ‘charbufferproc’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:167: error: field ‘len’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:168: error: field ‘itemsize’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:274: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘lenfunc’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:288: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘lenfunc’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:305: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘FILE’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:319: warning: ‘struct _typeobject’ declared inside parameter list /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:319: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:320: warning: ‘struct _typeobject’ declared inside parameter list /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:323: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:323: error: field ‘ob_size’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:325: error: field ‘tp_basicsize’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:325: error: field ‘tp_itemsize’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:370: error: field ‘tp_weaklistoffset’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:385: error: field ‘tp_dictoffset’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/object.h:456: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘FILE’ In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:81,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/objimpl.h:97: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/objimpl.h:98: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/objimpl.h:228: error: ‘PyGC_Collect’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/objimpl.h:249: error: field ‘gc_refs’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/objimpl.h:288: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:57:19: error: ctype.h: No such file or directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:120:21: error: wchar.h: No such file or directory In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:85,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:413: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:414: error: field ‘length’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:489: error: ‘PyUnicodeUCS2_GetSize’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:572: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘wchar_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:572: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:590: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘wchar_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:590: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:1234: error: ‘PyUnicodeUCS2_Tailmatch’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:1246: error: ‘PyUnicodeUCS2_Find’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/unicodeobject.h:1255: error: ‘PyUnicodeUCS2_Count’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:86,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/intobject.h:24: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/intobject.h:39: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/intobject.h:42: error: ‘PyInt_AsSsize_t’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:88,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/longobject.h:21: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/longobject.h:26: error: ‘PyLong_AsSsize_t’ declared as function returning a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/longobject.h:73: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_PyLong_NumBits’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/longobject.h:89: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/longobject.h:112: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘size_t’ In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:89,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/floatobject.h:15: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:91,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/complexobject.h:41: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:94,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/stringobject.h:36: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/stringobject.h:36: error: field ‘ob_size’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/stringobject.h:68: error: ‘PyString_Size’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:98,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/bytearrayobject.h:23: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/bytearrayobject.h:23: error: field ‘ob_size’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/bytearrayobject.h:26: error: field ‘ob_alloc’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/bytearrayobject.h:42: error: ‘PyByteArray_Size’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:99,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/tupleobject.h:25: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/tupleobject.h:25: error: field ‘ob_size’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/tupleobject.h:41: error: ‘PyTuple_Size’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:100,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/listobject.h:23: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/listobject.h:23: error: field ‘ob_size’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/listobject.h:38: error: field ‘allocated’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/listobject.h:48: error: ‘PyList_Size’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:101,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/dictobject.h:55: error: field ‘me_hash’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/dictobject.h:71: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/dictobject.h:72: error: field ‘ma_fill’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/dictobject.h:73: error: field ‘ma_used’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/dictobject.h:79: error: field ‘ma_mask’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/dictobject.h:109: error: ‘PyDict_Size’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:103,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/setobject.h:36: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/setobject.h:38: error: field ‘fill’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/setobject.h:39: error: field ‘used’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/setobject.h:45: error: field ‘mask’ declared as a function /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/setobject.h:85: error: ‘PySet_Size’ declared as function returning a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:104,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/methodobject.h:82: error: field ‘ob_refcnt’ declared as a function In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:106,

_mysql.c:660: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c:660: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_clear’:
_mysql.c:681: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c:681: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_type’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_close’:
_mysql.c:708: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_debug’:
_mysql.c:741: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_dump_debug_info’:
_mysql.c:763: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit’:
_mysql.c:789: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_commit’:
_mysql.c:811: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_rollback’:
_mysql.c:833: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_escape_string’:
_mysql.c:978: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c:990: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘_PyString_Resize’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_string_literal’:
_mysql.c:1016: error: ‘PyVarObject’ has no member named ‘ob_size’
_mysql.c:1017: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘PyString_FromStringAndSize’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c:1030: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘_PyString_Resize’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
_mysql.c:1031: error: ‘PyObject’ has no member named ‘ob_refcnt’ lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccFlerVi.out (No such file or directory) error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what os you are running, but for solaris 11 try
pkg install header-math